# How to convert a string to alphabets and add

Tags: java

i have a small project work given. the case is as follows.

i'm given a string and first i have to convert them into equivalent numbers and sum them up.

the numbers are as follows

```
a=1,b=2,c=3....z=4.
```

here another condition is

```
A==a==1;
```

A and a are same and similarly other letters caps and small are same.

Thanks

Comment: I didn't understand what is the project exactly. Can you explain it again? And by the way did you try anything? If so, please post your code.

Comment: tried to use charArray(), but didn't have any idea of

Answer (score 5):

```
String str = "ABcDe";
str = str.toUpperCase();//just to be sure you have only capital letters in your string

int sum=0;
for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){//cycle until the string ends
    sum = sum + str.charAt(i)-64;//'A' in ascii is 65, so 65-'A' = 65-64=1, etc
}
```

Comment: About to post the same thing Though to be less cryptic I'd use `-'A' + 1;`

Answer (score 0):

```
    //your input string
    String string = "Aab";

    char offset1 = 'a';
    char offset2 = 'A';
    int sum = 0;
    StringBuilder stringCode = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i=0; i<string.length(); i++){
        int curSymbol = string.charAt(i);
        if (curSymbol >= offset1){
            //caps
            int symbolNumber = curSymbol-offset1+1;
            stringCode.append(symbolNumber);
            sum += symbolNumber;
        }else{
            int symbolNumber = curSymbol-offset2+1;
            stringCode.append(symbolNumber);
            sum += symbolNumber;
        }
        stringCode.append(" ");
    }
    System.out.println("Strung code = "+stringCode.toString());
    System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
```